# Can I redirect abc.com/x to abc.com, where x is any non-existent subfolder?

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-redirect

I want a visit to any non-existent subfolder to redirect to the root, but a direct visit to the root to not have a redirect.

I'm experimenting with a .htaccess file, but the closest I got executed the redirect even on the root page, creating an infinite loop.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post it is unclear to me if you want to redirect all nonexistent pages to the root folder or if you want to redirect only specified ones. If you want to redirect all nonexistent pages try using a 404 page. If you are trying to redirect only specified pages try this website [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/08/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-using-htaccess).